# awk for loop with if else conditions to array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, awk, if-statement

I seek your help in storing awk returning values in an array for my awk for loop using if else conditions.

```
If  $3 == $7
then print $9 multiplied by $4
else print $4 multiplied by (2 minus $9)
```

I got this working so far by:

```
awk '{if ($3 == $7) print $9*$4; else print $4*(2-$9);}' file >outfile
```

the above code works for the first data column (`$9`). However, I want to loop through all columns from 9 to 1547 and return an array containing the returning values. This should be simple enough but I cant seem to understand some basic concepts here.

So far I understand the need to declare the number of loops, before the actual function, by:

> awk ' {for(i=9;i<=NF;i++)} END {if ($3 == $7) print $i*$4; else print $4*(2-$i);}'

However, how and when to declare the array is beyond me (biologist). Any help would be highly appreciated.

Example:

input (big file.. here column 1-10):

> rs2070501 22 A 0.0206 0.337855 rs2070501 G A 0.977 0.066

output:

> 0.0210738

here the else statement kicks in ($3 * (2-$9)

How to get awk to print out the array 9-Nth, and not just column 9

Comment: What do you mean by "return an array"?  Can you show sample input and output?

Comment: The `END` block is what happens when all rows have been read.  Do you mean something like `awk '{ for(i=9; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%s%i", (i==9 ? "" : " "), ($3 == $7 ? $i*$4 : $4*(2-$i)); printf "\n" }'` perhaps?

Comment: @triplee your code seems promising, but returns only "0" in every cell.  But has the right number of columns.

Comment: The `%i` formatting code is for integers; change it to `%f` for floats.

Comment: @general exception indeed.. All lines are processed, but not all columns.

Comment: triplee's code solved my problem, by replacing %i to %f. I am very greatful for all replies !

Comment: I get `0.021074 0.039840`, is your sample output correct?  I guess the rounding error is tolerable, but if you have ten input fields, there should be two output fields, shouldn't there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this.

```
awk '{
    for(i=9; i<=NF; ++i)
        printf "%s%f",
            (i==9 ? "" : " "),
            ($3 == $7 ? $i*$4 : $4*(2-$i));
    printf "\n"
}' filename
```

The `( test ? when : else )` is just a shorthand; the stuff after `?` gets evaluated if the test is true, and the stuff after `:` otherwise.  So it prints an empty separator for the first field, and a space otherwise; and chooses how to calculate the value of the field depending on whether `$3 == $7` is true.